# how can testng run 2nd package until the classes in 1st package are all finished?

Tags: testng

I use testng on IntelliJ IDEA, and my testng.xml file is like:

```
<suite name="test">
<test name="p0">
    <packages>
        <package name="UItest.first" />
        <package name="UItest.sencond" />
        <package name="UItest.three" />
    </packages>
</test>
</suite>
```

In first package, there're classes 1,2,3. Second package 4,5,6. Third package 7,8,9. When I run testng.xml, the sequence is 1,4,7,2,5,8,3,6,9. But what I want is 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9. So waht can I do?

Answer (score 0):

Currently your test cases are getting executed in parallel. You will have to set parallel execution to none, like below :

```
<suite name="test" parallel="none">
<test name="p0">
    <packages>
        <package name="UItest.first" />
        <package name="UItest.sencond" />
        <package name="UItest.three" />
    </packages>
</test>
</suite>
```

This should do the trick.

Comment: Can you share what output you got after making the change?

Comment: @Harjeb is your problem still exists, if yes can you share your output.